# Java function with parameters as two classes

Tags: java, function, class, object

I need to do the following thing:

```
class A
int length, width, height;

class B
int length, width, density;
```

(it is important that these classes has different parameters)

This is schema, not code. Now I would like to make a function which will do something like that:

```
function compare(class first, class second)
{
    if( first.length > second.length )
    { ... }
    else
    { ... }
}
```

and call that function: `compare(A,B)`.

Is it possible to do as I described it, or some better method exists?

Comment: totally possible to do. As you are using direct access to the member variables you will need to make them public.

Comment: class first, this is wrong.put A first.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class hirarchy. Define a super class contains length and width; have it implement Comparable and pass in the super class to do only comparison of length and width; then subclass to get your A and B class so that you don't compare the width/height by default.

Answer (score 0):

First, you define a superclass `A`.

```
public class A {
    private int length;

    public A(int length) {
       this.length = length'
    }

    public int getLength() { return length; }
}
```

And create two classes that subclass this, `B` and `C`.

```
public class B extends A { 
    public B(int length) {
       super(length);
    }
}

public class C extends A { 
    public B(int length) {
       super(length);
    }
}
```

And now you can create a method entitled:

```
public void compare(A first, A second) {
    if(first.getLength() > second.getLength()) {
         // Do something..
    }
}
```

And this can be called as follows:

```
A b = new B(5);

A c = new C(6);

compare(b, c);
```

Comment: why is inheritance even necessary?  Why have a Class C?

Comment: You could have an interface `C` I suppose, but given there was a common property that the user wanted to access, it made sense that I move that to a superclass.